# How to make results(pass/failed) on Django

Tags: django, forms

Hi All
I have next models

Case, Suite
I want to pass Case. For example I have next, in my html template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
            <input type="submit" value="Pass">
            <input type="submit" value="Failed">
        </form>
```

I want to add information about pressing button into database. I have view:

```
def main (request):
    result = Result(id=None, result='Pass', cashe=Case.objects.get(id=3), sudite=Suite.objects.get(id=2) )
    result.save()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        results = Result(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if results.is_valid():
         HERE WILL BE CLEANED DATA AND ETC, BUT AT 1st I WANT TO CHECK IT 
            pass
    return render_to_response('main.html', { 
                                             'suites': suites, 
                                             'cases': cases,
                                             'result': result,
                                             'host' : request.get_host()
                                             })
```

How to make it. I've read manual and search form works fine, but I don't know how to work with another buttons.

Anther interesting thing, that If I make it through shell, data successfully added. But If reload page on localhost/main I have next:

```
TypeError at /main/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case'
```

It's driving me crazy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the easiest way to do this is to give your submit buttons a `name` - call one `pass` and one `fail`, for example. Then, when your form gets submitted, check for the key `pass` or `fail` in `request.POST` - the button you clicked should be there, but the other one won't.

Comment: Sure: `<input type='submit' name='pass' value='Pass'><input type='submit' name='fail' value='Failed'>`

Comment: Oh, grate, but what should be in a view? Sorry :( I've tried to work with it, but ... it doesn't help.

Comment: In your view, you just do `if 'pass' in request.POST.keys()` to see if 'pass' was what the user clicked, or you test for `fail` to see if they clicked 'fail'.